# p5 js "can't read property 'show()' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, oop, object

What I am trying to do in this code is to take one dead particle, and make live ones cling to it and become dead in the process. At the end I would wish to have something that looks nice and is just a pleasurable program to watch.

But I have a problem...

My code will freeze at seemingly random points while running it and say "can't read property 'show()' of undefined."

The error is on line 18 when it tries to run the "live[i].show();"

sometimes it happens right away and sometimes it takes awhile but it always happens. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
var live = [];
var dead = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(255);
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    live.push(new particle(random(width), random(height), 1));
  }
  dead.push(new particle(width / 2, height / 2, 0))
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  if (live.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < live.length; i++) {
      live[i].update(i);
      live[i].show();
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < dead.length; i++) {
    dead[i].show();
  }
}

function particle(x, y, l) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.l = l;
  this.speed = 5;
  this.c = 200;
  this.s = 50;
}

particle.prototype.update = function(dex) {
  this.speed *= this.l;
  this.x += random(-this.speed, this.speed)
  this.y += random(-this.speed, this.speed)
  if (this.x < 0) {
    this.x = width;
  } else if (this.x > width) {
    this.x = 0;
  }
  if (this.y < 0) {
    this.y = height;
  } else if (this.y > height) {
    this.y = 0;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < dead.length; i++) {
    if (dist(dead[i].x, dead[i].y, this.x, this.y) < this.s && dist(dead[i].x, dead[i].y, this.x, this.y) > 0) {
      dead.push(new particle(this.x, this.y, 0));
      live.splice(dex, 1);
    }
  }
}

particle.prototype.show = function() {
  this.c *= this.l;
  strokeWeight(this.s);
  stroke(this.c);
  point(this.x, this.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace loop in the draw method with map it will solve your problem.

```
function draw() {
  background(255);

  live.map(function(curr,i){
    curr.update(i);
    curr.show();
  })

  dead.map(function(curr){
    curr.show();
  })
}
```

here is the plunkr of the updated code https://plnkr.co/edit/j5ueccmK4o7kbNKfeYQJ The error was caused because it was trying to access array larger than the maximum index of the array.

This is caused because you are mutating the array using splice in update method and it reduces its length while the for loop with previous length tries to loop the array beyond its length causing undefined.

Edit:
It is better to reduce the mutation in the code to avoid these errors.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even know about the .map() function! I'm going to need this quite a bit!